# Why does angular2 renderer hides the app when setting styles on body element

Tags: angular

Using the code below the body styles gets set but the app gets hidden resulting to a blank page.

Why this behaviour? Or is it a bug?

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.renderer.selectRootElement('body'), 'height', '100%');
```

Comment: Are you sure the app is hidden? and not collapsed to height = 0? height=100% doesn't mean anything in CSS, try 100vh instead of 100%

Comment: Just confirmed it, it does wipe off the body content, interesting

Comment: Happens with any style that you set

Comment: Actually this.render.selectRootElement(document.body) is removing all contents of body.